# mapply in R Error "Error in dots[[1L]][[1L]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

Tags: r, mapply

I have this code: `mapply(annotate, maxs, s, ann)`
Where annotate is a function that takes an annotator object (maxs), a string (s), and an annotated object (ann). s is a list of string and ann an equal-in-length list of annotated objects.

This is the error I am getting:

> Error in dots[[1L]][[1L]] : object of type 'closure' is not
>   subsettable

Info & Code:

```
 s <- c("hello world", "hello world")                                                                             

require(openNLP)
    require(NLP)
    require(openNLPmodels.en)
    require(tm) #optional
    require(hash) #optional
    require(openNLPdata) #optional  


sent_token_annotator <- Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator()
    word_token_annotator <- Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator()
    pos_tag_annotator <- Maxent_POS_Tag_Annotator()

    ann <- sapply(s, annotate, list(sent_token_annotator,
                                   word_token_annotator,
                                   pos_tag_annotator))

maxs<-Maxent_Chunk_Annotator(probs = FALSE)

> maxs; str(maxs); s; str(s); ann; str(ann);
An annotator inheriting from classes
  Simple_Chunk_Annotator Annotator
with description
  Computes chunk annotations using the Apache OpenNLP Maxent chunker employing the default model for language 'en'.
function (s, a)  
 - attr(*, "meta")=List of 1
  ..$ description: chr "Computes chunk annotations using the Apache OpenNLP Maxent chunker employing the default model for language 'en'."
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "Simple_Chunk_Annotator" "Annotator"
[1] "hello world" "hello world"
 chr [1:2] "hello world" "hello world"
 id type     start end features
  1 sentence     1  23 constituents=<<integer,4>>
  2 word         1   5 POS=UH
  3 word         7  11 POS=NN
  4 word        13  17 POS=UH
  5 word        19  23 POS=NN
List of 5
 $ :Classes 'Annotation', 'Span'  hidden list of 5
  ..$ id      : int 1
  ..$ type    : chr "sentence"
  ..$ start   : int 1
  ..$ end     : int 23
  ..$ features:List of 1
  .. ..$ :List of 1
  .. .. ..$ constituents: int [1:4] 2 3 4 5
  ..- attr(*, "meta")=List of 2
  .. ..$ POS_tagset    : chr "en-ptb"
  .. ..$ POS_tagset_URL: chr "http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/ccalas/tagsets/upenn.html"
 $ :Classes 'Annotation', 'Span'  hidden list of 5
  ..$ id      : int 2
  ..$ type    : chr "word"
  ..$ start   : int 1
  ..$ end     : int 5
  ..$ features:List of 1
  .. ..$ :List of 1
  .. .. ..$ POS: chr "UH"
  ..- attr(*, "meta")=List of 2
  .. ..$ POS_tagset    : chr "en-ptb"
  .. ..$ POS_tagset_URL: chr "http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/ccalas/tagsets/upenn.html"
 $ :Classes 'Annotation', 'Span'  hidden list of 5
  ..$ id      : int 3
  ..$ type    : chr "word"
  ..$ start   : int 7
  ..$ end     : int 11
  ..$ features:List of 1
  .. ..$ :List of 1
  .. .. ..$ POS: chr "NN"
  ..- attr(*, "meta")=List of 2
  .. ..$ POS_tagset    : chr "en-ptb"
  .. ..$ POS_tagset_URL: chr "http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/ccalas/tagsets/upenn.html"
 $ :Classes 'Annotation', 'Span'  hidden list of 5
  ..$ id      : int 4
  ..$ type    : chr "word"
  ..$ start   : int 13
  ..$ end     : int 17
  ..$ features:List of 1
  .. ..$ :List of 1
  .. .. ..$ POS: chr "UH"
  ..- attr(*, "meta")=List of 2
  .. ..$ POS_tagset    : chr "en-ptb"
  .. ..$ POS_tagset_URL: chr "http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/ccalas/tagsets/upenn.html"
 $ :Classes 'Annotation', 'Span'  hidden list of 5
  ..$ id      : int 5
  ..$ type    : chr "word"
  ..$ start   : int 19
  ..$ end     : int 23
  ..$ features:List of 1
  .. ..$ :List of 1
  .. .. ..$ POS: chr "NN"
  ..- attr(*, "meta")=List of 2
  .. ..$ POS_tagset    : chr "en-ptb"
  .. ..$ POS_tagset_URL: chr "http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/ccalas/tagsets/upenn.html"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "Annotation" "Span"
 - attr(*, "meta")=List of 2
  ..$ POS_tagset    : chr "en-ptb"
  ..$ POS_tagset_URL: chr "http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/ccalas/tagsets/upenn.html"
```

`

Your help is very appreciated! TY

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example with data. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Most likely some bug in your code. Can you provide example data, or show at least the result of `annotate`, `str(maxs)` `str(s)` `str(ann)`?

Comment: TY. Updated the question. TY.

Comment: What package are you using? Please post your actual code block including all `library` lines and all necessary lines prior to `mapply`.

Comment: I updated the question. TY.

Comment: Any Help Appreciated!